# For all $z$ and prime $p > z^2$, is $p \geq z^{-1}+z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a certain modular relationship that I'm trying to prove something about; critical to that is a simple relationship involving an integer, and its inverse, on $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  In my relationship, I have an integer $r < z$, and two reductions that concern $r$:
$$
\begin{align}
x &\equiv r_0\ \bmod p \\
y &\equiv z^{-1} + r_1\ \bmod p
\end{align}
$$

I wish to prove that $x$ and $y$, the remainders modulo $p$, are such that $y \geqslant x$ for all $z$, $r<z$, for the special case where $p>z^2$.  It is likely the case that $y \geqslant x$ for small values of $r_1$; that is because the least positive integer inverse $z^{-1}$ is less than $p$.  However, when $r_1$ gets large, could the sum *wrap around* $p$, causing a situation where $x$ could be greater than $y$?  I have reduced this situation to the maximum case on $r_1$, and phrased the question in general terms below (with clarifications suggested from the comments).  Based on the answer, it has been proven generally that $y \geqslant x$ given my conditions.  Here is the generalized question:

Given a prime $p$ and integer $z>1$ such that $p > z^2$, and a least positive integer $z^{-1}$ such that $z\cdot z^{-1} \equiv 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$, is it generally true that $p$ is greater than the sum of $z$ and its inverse on $p$, or $p \geq z^{-1}+z$?

Example: If $z=3$, $p=11$, then $z^{-1} \equiv 4\bmod 11$, and $4+3 \leq 11$.  If $p=13$, then $z^{-1}=9$ and the sum comes to 12.  Trying 4 on 17, inverse is 13, sums to 17.

Can someone give me an intuition (if not a proof - intuition is fine)?

Comment: I get queasy mixing up integers and congruence classes.  In your first example, what if you took $z^{-1}$ to be 15?

Comment: To second Randall, once you start talking about congruence class in modular arithmetic, the integers no longer have a natural ordering, so inequalities don't necessarily have meaning.

Comment: See that $2+3>5$ and $2\cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $2<\sqrt{5}.$

Comment: @B.Goddard $2 + 3 = 5$, not $> 5$.

Comment: Can you clarify whether $z^{-1}$ is meant to denote the least positive integer $k$ such that $z\cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, @Russ?

Comment: Yes.  The notation $z^{-1}$ means the modular inverse of $z$ on $p$, such that $z\cdot z^{-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$.  I've always treated $z^{-1}$ as being less than $p$.

Comment: Edit that into the question please, so that the ambiguity mentioned in the first comments is removed.

Comment: @DanielFischer done.  Thanks!

Comment: The ambiguous part is the "least positive". The first comment raises the question what happens if you pick a different representative of the residue class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is the least positive integer such that $z\cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then $0 < k < p$. Writing
$$z\cdot k = m\cdot p + 1$$
it follows that $m < z$. Writing $m = z - \ell$ we obtain
$$k = \frac{(z-\ell)p + 1}{z} = p - \frac{\ell p - 1}{z} \leqslant p - \frac{p-1}{z}\,.$$
Since by assumption $p > z^2$ we have $\frac{p-1}{z} \geqslant z$, and thus $k \leqslant p - z$ follows.

Comment: Can you help me understand why $\frac{p-1}{z} \geqslant z$?

Comment: @Russ From the assumption $p > z^2$, since both, $p$ and $z$, are integers, we obtain $p-1 \geqslant z^2$. And since $z > 0$, dividing this inequality by $z$ yields $\frac{p-1}{z} \geqslant z$.

Comment: I see.  And then $k \leqslant p - \frac{p-1}{z} \leqslant p - z$.  Thanks so much!